# Looking for the best way to communicate data between Model view and controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller, codeigniter-3

I am a very new programmer so please forgive me if you find my question stupid.
I am working with Codeigniter and I have a method `get_projects()` in Projects model to read data from projects table. here is the code.

```
public function get_projects ($userid = '')
{
    if (empty($userid))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
     $return_data = array();
        $this->db->select('id, startdate, projectname, expenddate, amount, advance, dues');
        $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
        $query = $this->db->get('projects');
        if($query->row())
            $return_data = $query->row();
        return $return_data;                  
}
```

I have a controller function `get_projects()` in which I am trying to call this model method and pass data to View file. Here is the code.

```
 public function get_projects()
{
    $userid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $projects = $this->projects->get_projects($userid);
    $data = array(
        'projectname' => '',
        'startdate'   => ''            
    );
    $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
}
```

I have a view file called `dashboard.php` and want to show there. I am updating my question to show the view file.

```
    <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
<section>
    <div class="row topspace">
        <div class="col-6 offset-3">
            <h4 class="text-center">Dashboard Testing</h4><hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>  
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row->projectname; ?></h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><?php echo $row->startdate; ?></h6>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

How do I do this? What is the correct way to send data from the controller to view file and what is the correct way to access that data in the view file?
Please help me figure this out I have trying for last 5 hours. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure how many rows you are fetching.

`row()` is for one record and `result()` for more than one

**Model**

```
 public function get_projects ($userid = '')
 {
   if (empty($userid)){
     return FALSE;
   }
   $this->db->select('id, startdate, projectname, expenddate, amount, advance, dues');
   $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
   $query = $this->db->get('projects');

   //Another way is to count rows and then use row() or result()
   //$query->num_rows() will tell you how many rows you are getting

   if($query->num_rows() == 1){
        return $query->row();
    }else{
        return $query->result();
    }                  
 }
```

**Controller**

```
 public function get_projects(){

   $userid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
   $projects = $this->projects->get_projects($userid);

   //Here pass `$projects` data to array and give it to view
   $data = array(
        'projectname' => $projects, 
        'startdate'   => 'your-date'
   );
   $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
}
```

Now show data in the view. If rows are more than one use `foreach()` loop otherwise without loop

Comment: I have startdate and other details stored in database. Once I return result() from model how do I access all details in controller and also in view. Please elaborate, this is my first time doing this.

Comment: @Rishav according to my answer, In controller you are getting project record from DB in `$projects` variable. Then you are passing this in the form of another array `$data`. In controller you can use projects data with `$projects` variable. In your view you can access projects data with `$projectname` variable name

Comment: i need to access only some attributes of the whole result set.

Comment: see in controller $data = array('projectname' => $projetcs->projectname, 'startdate'-> $projects->startdate) ; . Can I do something like this.

Comment: No no. Do like this `$data = array('projectname' => $projetcs, 'startdate' => 'other-value') ;`

Comment: see i have all data in result array. i want to show all data in view . so i have to pass from controller . please show me how to read startdate from database in model pass it on to controller and thereafter to view. I am sorry if my understanding is limited. Please bear with me.

Comment: Onether request, if you have 5 minutes time I would like to connect on anydesk please.

Comment: Is `startdate` in the `projects` table?

Comment: you don't need to pass it separately you can get it from `$projects` variable.

Comment: In the view `$projectname->startdate;`

Comment: This has solved everything. Thank you sir for your help. I wish you all the best in life. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first load your model:

```
$mymodel = $this->load->model('namemodel')
```

Then access to your model function:

```
$result = $mymodel->get_projects(useridgohere)
```

And you have result in your `$result` var.

For reading in view you could put in your variable data your result

```
$data = array(
   'thenameofvariableinview' => $result,
);
$this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
```

Then in view you can call with:

```
<?php 
   echo $thenameofvariableinview; 
?>
```

Comment: Add your view php and i could help you!

Comment: hello sir, but onece I return the result row from model , this row has many attributes right. I want to access these from controller and then pass on to the view file. I am updating my question to show the view file.

Comment: Just acess with array like `$result['name']`

Answer (score 0):

**Model:**

```
public function get_projects ($userid = '')
 {
   if (!empty($userid))
   {
      $this->db->select('id, startdate, projectname, expenddate, amount, advance, dues');
      $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
      $query = $this->db->get('projects');
      if($query->num_rows() > 0){
          return $query->row();
          //return $query->result();//according to your requirment like loop
      }else{
          return array();//empty array
      }
    }else{
       return array();//empty array
    }              
 }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function get_projects(){

   $data = array()
   $this->load->model('Project_model');//assums not loaded in autoload
   $userid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
   $results = $this->Project_model->get_projects($userid);//always add _model to avoid confusion

   //$results->startdate = '';//you can do this too
   $data['result'] = $results;
   $data['startdate'] = '';//dont forget to add date
   $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
<section>
    <div class="row topspace">
        <div class="col-6 offset-3">
            <h4 class="text-center">Dashboard Testing</h4><hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <?php if (!empty($result) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>  
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row->projectname; ?></h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><?php echo $startdate; ?></h6>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php }else{ ?>
          <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">No data found.</h5>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
</section>
```